Ansible lint complain about missing ansiblelint/data/.yamllint on GitHub Actions
I install ansible-lint by
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --target tmp/

The installed version is 24.9.0
Locally, everything is fine.
But when I run it on GitHub Actions, it complains about

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tmp/ansiblelint/data/.yamllint'

If I make an ls -la inside that folder, the file is not there (which is coherent with the message)
Any idea?
** Added **
which ansible-lint
xxx/tmp/bin/ansible-lint

type ansible-lint
ansible-lint is xxx/tmp/bin/ansible-lint


Why not install ansible-lint normally, or use the ansible-lint container image for the GHA agent?
